# How to write a program to print the wishes based on the sys time?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

In PL/SQL Block, I would like to print the 'Good Morning','Good Noon','Good Eve' based on the system time that I have given as input.
If the time is 6 AM to 12 PM then it has to print GOOD MORNING 
else if 
it lies between 12 PM to 2 PM 
it has to print GOOD NOON 
else if it has to print GOOD EVE. So anybody can give me the Idea? 
Advance Thanks for everyone who gives me the guidance.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use Date/Time functions in a control structure

Comment: @kittykittybangbang **Wishes Program:** (begin if to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mm:ss') between to_char('08:00:00') and to_char('12:00:00') then dbms_output.put_line('Gud Mrg'); elsif --------OTHER CONDITIONS---------- else dbms_output.put_line('Gud Nt'); end if; end; / )_It will gives the output as I expected._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you know how the anonymous block looks like (reminder below):

```
DECLARE
  -- variables' / constants' / types' / etc. declarations
BEGIN
  -- logic
END;
/
```

You can create DATE variables or constants as follows:

```
l_in_date <CONSTANT> DATE := TO_DATE(<date>,<date_mask>);
```

Then you can use IF..THEN statement and print out the result according to the conditions (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php):

```
IF <condition> THEN
  -- logic
ELSIF <condition> THEN
  -- logic
ELSE
  -- logic
END IF;
```

I believe, you should be able to create your anonymous block easily using the information above.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a procedure or function that looks what time it is from the 24 hour format.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, HH24:MI:SS') INTO sysDate FROM dual;
```

Here `sysDate` is the current time in 24 hour format. 
Then look if a time is within a certain timespan.

Comment: Cool thank you so much.... I didnt aware of that HH Mm Ss format... So now i got a clear idea.